# AIR for Android Audio Record

Tags: flash, air, audio-recording

I am building an android app using Flash CC and Adobe AIR. I want to add a feature where I can record user spoken audio and then change its pitch and replay the same. To add Audio Record feature I got this (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-useful-audio-recorder-app-in-actionscript-3--active-5836) tutorial but the audio is not playing (It gets saved to sdCard, but time of the audio shows 0:00). Can anyone point me to a solution?

Comment: Try to verify the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission of your app.

Comment: I have given all the required functions, the music gets saved but it shows 0:00 as music time which means no sound bytes are recorded.

Comment: Did you see your file saved ? Did you try to play it ?

Comment: yes. I saved it to sdcard, and tried to play it too

Comment: But in your question you told us the inverse !! Could you play it ?

Comment: my bad. I re-framed the question. The audio gets saved but of 0:00 time means nothing plays on clicking the play button. Its just starts and stops immidiately.